# Using Vlookup in a macro function

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I need to use Vlookup macro =VLOOKUP(E2,[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D,4,FALSE) for every cell until it ends. I'm not sure how to use long instead of range. When I use range it sometimes goes over because I predict wrong and I want everything to be automated, can anyone help please? instead of the E2 I need it to go through all of them but I want to incorporate it into my macro.

```
Sub Work()
Dim LR As Long
Dim row As String
row = "E2"
row = "E" & x
LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Range(Columns(6), Columns(7)).Select
For x = 0 To 2
row = "E" & x
Range("F2:F" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & row & ",[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D,4,FALSE)"
Next




End Sub
```

Comment: You want to do that for each row? (E2, E3, E4, ...)

Comment: Possibliy record a macro...do some research....edit it...then share some of your research on stackoverflow....

Comment: epsilon, not each row just all the way down the E column and Vasim I have, let me post, hold on.

Comment: Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F33547"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F2:F33547").Select
End Sub

Comment: that is my recorded macro, but I it goes past my other column lengths, and I want it to be automated. I dont want to have to check the other workbook for its column length then change my macro

Comment: sorry epsilon I read it wrong yes, I want to do it for every row

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what JDuarteDJ said, using a variable to loop through the rows would likely work best. However, you mentioned sometimes you predict the number of rows incorrectly. You could use:

> rowCount = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

This will give you the count of the rows with somthing in them in column F. Then you can do the same loop that JDuarteDJ mentioned only instead of

> x = 2 to 20

You could use

> For x = 2 to rowCount 
>   
>   ' Do all things previously mentioned and whatver you need to do
>   
>  Next

Hope this helps

-------------UPDATE---------------------------

The problem with the edit, I THINK, is that within your for loop, you're using:

> Range("F2:F" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(&row&,[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D,4,FALSE)"

Which is isn't iterating through the correct number of times. What you want to be doing in my opinion is looping from 2 to the number of rows, like this:

> For x = 2 to LR
>   
>   Range("F2:F" & X).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(&row&,[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D,4,FALSE)"

Comment: column F is blank until vlookup inserted, so I should use a different column right?

Comment: Right, it will return a column count of 1 I believe. If you have another column that will have the same number of rows as F, you can use this just to get the Row count.

Comment: im not sure how to get this going I feel like nothing is getting output when I keep running my attempts

Comment: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(F2:8), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: how do I replace the add with F(Rowcount)

Comment: I need a faster more efficient code wow, I just attempted to run something and my system is unusable

Comment: F(Rowcount) is kind of meaningless unless you concatenate it properly like JDuarteDJ mentioned. I think I may be confused by what you're trying to do. My answer is just a way to get an accurate number of rows so you know how many times to execute your code. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: To use Rowcount there you could try: Range(Cells(2,6),Cells(Rowcount,6)) (6 Corresponds to F and the first number is the row number of the start and end of your range.

Comment: Sub Work()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Columns("F").Insert

Range("F2:F" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC,[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:D,4,FALSE)"
End Sub

Comment: instead of RC, I need that to increment like E1, E2, E3

Comment: AHHH IM so close someone please help

Comment: I editted my post that code takes it down but the &row& messes it up

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer as well. I think your For loop is currently messing you up.

Comment: right as you put that I found something that works check my updated post, but thank you so much, Im going to try yours too, mine is running sloe

Comment: Ok, no problem glad you got it figured out!

Comment: actually, everytime it runs it shifts over a column to the right and screws up my spacing, any idea?

Comment: I know it has something to do with the insert

Comment: "  row = "E" & x  " <-- should this line read "  row = "F" & x    "

Comment: hmmm, Thanks, I'll show you what I did to fix it, check my update post in three

Comment: it finally works the way I needed it too, thank you everyone who helped, especially confused_footballer

Answer (score 0):

Replace E2 for a variable:

> Dim row as String
>   row = "E2"

then use a loop to iterate through all E2,E3,E4 etc.

> For x=2 to 20 do
>   row = "E" & x
>   formula = "VLOOKUP("&row&",[gpic.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D,4,FALSE)"
>   ... use your code here ...

My VB may be a little rusty :/
Hope this helps

Comment: getting ready to test it out, Im going to let you know how it goes thank you